# PHP Curl Keep Proxy connection live

Tags: php, curl

CURLOPT_VERBOSE explains, the system takes time for connecting to PROXY before it actually makes a request to a web link.

```
$ch = curl_init("$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$ip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "$po");



$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$errmsg = curl_error($ch); 
$cInfo = curl_getinfo($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

I want to execute multiple links without closing curl to reduce latency. Is there any way to keep the PROXY live and do multiple requests to links?

Answer (score 2):

When curl uses a proxy, the connection keeps open until the call of curl_close.

Two important points,

1. First/initial proxy connection always gonna take time (latency)
2. When the connection is established, don't close the connection, simply adjust parameters according to the requirements.

For an example:

```
//$ch = curl_init("$url");
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$ip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "$po");



curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Request One
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$errmsg = curl_error($ch); 
$cInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Request Two
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$errmsg = curl_error($ch); 
$cInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Request Three
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$errmsg = curl_error($ch); 
$cInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch); //Closing after all requests
```

The first request will take some time in connection establishment to the proxy which depends on multiple factors. After the first request, all requests will be faster and will happen based on actual proxy speed(provided server script >= proxy speed).

I think we can't do the persistent connection. If you know how to do that, please share :-)